# Displaying Images(numbers) to screen

Tags: android, image

I am working on a project that will display math problems to the screen such as:

10 + 5 =

and then the user will need to guess the answer. I am doing this as more of way for me to learn how android ticks.

I have images from 0 to 9 saved in the drawable folder for each of the dpi setting I need to account. I also have the operators (+,-,*,/,=) also saved.

My questions:

1. How easy is this to do?
2. How would I go about doing the above dynamically?

Thanks

--EDIT--
The images and operators are stored as .9.png files in my drawable folder. I have string-array contain my problems that I will randomly pull from and then display them to the screen.

In the past I would do the following:

```
public View buildProblem()
{

    LinearLayout rtnView = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    rtnView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    rtnView.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams());

    // Build LeftSide
    Iterator<Integer> itor = buildLeftSide();
    ImageView iv;
    // loop through of iterator
    while(itor.hasNext())
    {
        iv = new ImageView(ctx);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        iv.setImageResource(itor.next());
        itor.remove();
        rtnView.addView(iv);
    }
    // Space
    rtnView.addView(space);
    // Operator
    rtnView.addView(plusSign);
    // Build LeftSide
    itor = buildRightSide();
    // another loop
    while(itor.hasNext())
    {
        iv = new ImageView(ctx);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        iv.setImageResource(itor.next());
        itor.remove();
        rtnView.addView(iv);
    }
    // Space
    rtnView.addView(space);
    // Equal Sign
    rtnView.addView(equalSign);
    // Space
    rtnView.addView(space);
    // return the view
    return rtnView;
}
```

I was thinking of using ImageViews for the numbers to be displayed to the screen which I have used in the past but not sure if that is the best way to do it.

https://github.com/barakisbrown/MathTest -- Is one attempt at doing the above but I have now started to rewrite it from scratch so which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: you want to draw this formula on your bitmap ??

Comment: Are you running this in a custom view? need to explain a bit about you app since there are many ways to do this

Comment: This question is off-topic because it appears to be a request for someone else to write the code or explain how to write the code, and does not identify a specific problem or question about programming. Please include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differed from the expected results, and any error messages you received. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask